# Changing vSphere License Key

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vcenter

I have some vSPhere 4 standard licensed hosts in vCenter that had the key entered during install. I now want to change the licese key for these servers to use new Enteprrise Plus licenses that are controlled by vCenter, but I cant seem to do this. I have tried removing the keys but it won't let me, if I try to assign new unassigned keys they are greyed out within vCenter (they are fine to apply to new hosts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inherently must have a valid support contract with VMWare right now - have you asked them?

Answer (score 0):

This is the [official procedure](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/licensing_howto_guide.pdf) and should work:

In vCenter Home Screen -> Licensing.
Select one if your hosts, right click and select 'Change License Key'

Answer (score 0):

If the key is greyed out, that usually means you are trying to use the wrong type of key to license the host. Make sure the key you are using matches both what features the host is using as well as the version of ESXi